# Why `git checkout -` works differently in a Makefile?

Tags: git, makefile

I have such a beautiful target in my Makefile which works in bash without a problem. `git checkout -` should checkout a previous branch, but it doesn't, it stays in that develop branch and that's it, while executing this in bash it works well. Do I have bad if statement maybe? In Makefile you need to you double dollar sign in order to have a bash subcommand right?

```
SHELL := /bin/bash

rebase:
     git stash
     git checkout develop
     git pull --rebase origin develop
     if [ $$(git status --porcelain | wc -l) -lt 1 ]; then \
         git checkout -;\
         git rebase develop;\
         git stash apply;\
     fi;
```

Comment: you could add some echo to the if block to rule out shell logic issues

Comment: You right - it was one file which haven't been added anywhere and it was untraced one, so I've added `git stash --include-untracked`

Comment: Note: `git config pull.rebase true; git config rebase.autoStash true` can be of interest here: no need for stashing: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30209750/6309

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the '`-`' is somehow misinterpreted, try the alternative syntax `@{-1}`.

Both are [mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7207542/6309).
The [`if`/`then` shell syntax used in Makefile](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30773906/6309) seems correct.

Comment: Not sure I interpreted the last part correctly but the `if/then/fi` syntax has nothing to do with `GNU make`, it's shell syntax.

Comment: @Tim Yes, I meant the "shell syntax used in that Makefile". I have edited the answer.