# nmake behaviour on windows

Tags: c++, windows, makefile, nmake

### overwiew

I want to use nmake on windows however got stuck with ifeq not being supported to achieve something I am trying to get. [OS detecting makefile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/714100/os-detecting-makefile)

### workaround

To workaround the ifeq incompatibility, I decided to use **$(OS)** attribute.

```
include platf/$(OS)_make
```

- windows it is supposed to include **platf/Windows_NT_make**
- other platforms where $(OS) returns "", so uses file **platf/_make**

Directory layout

```
|   Makefile
+---platf
|       Makefile.linux
|       Makefile.macos
|       Makefile.win
|       Windows_NT_make
|       _make
```

### problem

- **_make**, I have the same routine from [OS detecting makefile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/714100/os-detecting-makefile) and include Makefile for linux, or mac etc
- **Windows_NT_make** includes Makefile.win

This works like charm, except windows again.

#1 If the file platf/Windows_NT_make **IS** present, it complains with

> makefile(4) : fatal error U1052: file 'platf/$(OS)_make' not found

#2 If the file platf/Windows_NT_make **IS NOT** present, it complains with

> makefile(4) : fatal error U1052: file 'platf/Windows_NT_make' not found

### Question

So, if nmake is able to decide what would be the value of $(OS) is (seen from #2), why it complains with #1

Comment: Save yourself the trouble and use CMake.

Comment: Yes, that's what I found most people talk about nmake.I plan to switch to ant (with cpptasks) to avoid platform dependent conflicts.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the slash character that delineates the platf directory from the Makefile name.
It needs to be "/" for unix family and "\" for Windows.

You need to know which OS to correctly form the name. This can be solved in a couple of ways:

1. Not using a subdirectory
2. Doing a separate CD so names are local

I solve the problem by having one makefile and using a portable script file to determine the OS and edit the Makefile (using sed) appropriately. With one script and one makefile I can move across all systems.