# How do distinguish between platforms (Windows/Linux) in console or makefile

Tags: bash, cmd, terminal, gnu-make

I have a Makefile that is intended to be used both on Linux and Windows. I need to be able to somehow distinguish between platforms to be able to alternate targets for them.

Another possible difficulty could be that this makefile could be run inside Cygwin or Git bash on Windows, but it still should be able to know, that it's on Windows and not break.

How do I do such a thing?

Comment: use `Makefile-win32`...

Comment: I already use GnuWin32 make.

Comment: uname command should return something different in each context.

Comment: On Windows, when I try $(shell uname) it gives this output: process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, uname, ...) failed.

Comment: Using Cygwin, $(uname) gives `CYGWIN_NT-6.1`.

Comment: This might help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/714100/os-detecting-makefile