# Platform-dependent Makefile

Tags: makefile

I read [OS detecting makefile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/714100/os-detecting-makefile), but I'd rather have two different Makefile, one for Windows and one for Linux, and source them from inside the main Makefile. Something like:

```
ifeq ($(OS),Windows_NT)
    # run the commands in the MakefileWin file
else
    # run the commands in the MakefileLinux file
endif
```

Is it possible without a shell script, just using make commands? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not just use `include`?

```
ifeq ($(OS),Windows_NT)
  include Makefilewin
else
  include MakefileLinux
endif
```

?