# Using a portable Makefile for AWS Lambda

Tags: makefile, aws-lambda, gnu-make, aws-sam, aws-sam-cli

I'm using a Makefile for building a lambda extension. It works fine when I run a `sam build` command from Azure DevOps using Ubuntu. However, sometimes I want to build from my PC and the Makefile doesn't work because commands are different. I suppose I could setup command aliases for dos but that seems treacherous. I'd prefer to use something like [OS detecting makefile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/714100/os-detecting-makefile) but when I tried that it didn't work out.

Here's the pertinent snippet from my template:

```
  TokenCacheLayer:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::LayerVersion
    Metadata:
      BuildMethod: makefile
    Properties:
      LayerName: !Ref TokenCacheLayerName
      Description: AWS Lambda extension to cache tokens aquired from an external API.
      ContentUri: ./token-cache
      LicenseInfo: MIT-0
      CompatibleRuntimes:
        - nodejs12.x
      RetentionPolicy: Retain
```

Here's my Makefile:

```
build-TokenCacheLayer:
    cp -R extensions "$(ARTIFACTS_DIR)"
    cp -R token-cache-extension "$(ARTIFACTS_DIR)"
```

Here's the 2 ways I've tried altering to make it OS independent:

```
build-TokenCacheLayer:
    ifeq ($(OS),Windows_NT)
        xcopy extensions "$(ARTIFACTS_DIR)\extensions"
        xcopy token-cache-extension "$(ARTIFACTS_DIR)"
    else
        cp -R extensions "$(ARTIFACTS_DIR)"
        cp -R token-cache-extension "$(ARTIFACTS_DIR)"
    endif
```

and

```
ifeq ($(OS),Windows_NT)
    build-TokenCacheLayer:
        xcopy extensions "$(ARTIFACTS_DIR)\extensions"
        xcopy token-cache-extension "$(ARTIFACTS_DIR)"
else
    build-TokenCacheLayer:
        cp -R extensions "$(ARTIFACTS_DIR)"
        cp -R token-cache-extension "$(ARTIFACTS_DIR)"
endif
```

The first way I got the error:

```
Error: CustomMakeBuilder:MakeBuild - Make Failed: process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, cp -R extensions D:\Development\AWS.Integration\buildpro\layers\sam-build\TokenCacheLayer, ...) failed.
make (e=2): The system cannot find the file specified.
make: *** [D:\Development\AWS.Integration\buildpro\layers\token-cache\Makefile:6: build-TokenCacheLayer] Error 2
```

The second gave me this:

```
Error: CustomMakeBuilder:MakeBuild - Make Failed: D:\Development\AWS.Integration\buildpro\layers\token-cache\Makefile:2: *** recipe commences before first target.  Stop.
```

### Update

I went back and tried the first way again and while I'm not getting an error it doesn't copy the files either.

Comment: Indenting is usually good to keep track of if-else, but in a Makefile you will probably have to do without that indenting. Also, you will need to make sure that the commands are indented with a tab.

Comment: When you say _I want to build from my PC_ I suppose you really mean you want to build on a Windows system?

Comment: In the non-WINDOWS_NT branch, does that OS understand paths where the directory separator is a backslash?

Comment: @MadScientist - yes. My local machine is Windows 10. When I build in Azure Pipeline I specify Ubuntu.

Comment: @Jens - I haven't attempted to build in Azure Pipelines with Ubuntu yet. I'll try checking in my code and see what happens.