# passing strings to a make file

Tags: gnu-make

I would like to do the following. I don't know whether it's possible to do it. If possible I would like to know how to do it.

```
make VAR1=arg1,arg2,arg3
```

based on the arg I would like to pass a switch to gcc.

For example,

if arg1 and arg2 are passed I would like to define a switch and if arg2 and arg3 are passed I would like to define another switch in the make file. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `make VAR1="arg1 arg2 arg3"` with this in the makefile:

```
ifeq (arg1 arg2,$(findstring arg1,$(VAR1)) $(findstring arg2,$(VAR1)))
# define a switch
endif

ifeq (arg2 arg3,$(findstring arg2,$(VAR1)) $(findstring arg3,$(VAR1)))
# define another switch
endif
```

If there are a lot of these switches, you can define a macro to simplify the makefile.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check GMSL?

http://gmsl.sourceforge.net/

```
conditional-directive
text-if-true
endif
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/180818/643500

...

if you want to pass it seperated by commas, then you can split the string and pass it to the if statements.